# Uninstalled module still populating in cron_schedule table

Tags: module, cron, magento-1.14, ee-1.14, uninstall

I've uninstalled an extension but it's cron jobs keep repopulating in the cron_schedule table. The steps I have taken are..

1. disable magento cron via `crontab -e -u apache`
2. Uninstalled the module using the ./mage command line tool
3. `grep -r "bronto"` . and removed any leftover files
4. Removed the module tables from the database.
5. `truncate cron_schedule`
6. Enable crontab

The task cannot execute because the module does not exist, however it still shows up in cron_schedule

Comment: check core_config_data table, maybe the cron of this module exists there

Comment: Flush the `Configuration Cache` to make sure Magento doesn't think your module is still enabled.

Comment: Simon, I didn't realized cron schedules could live here. Digging through this table has resolved the issue.